# Ionic: How to create a databound listview?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Android has `RecyclerView`, WPF has `ListView`, etc. I think that Ionic-equivalent is probably `ion-list`. If I have a list of strings, such as

```
Animals:string[] = ["Dog", "Cat", "Human", "Crab"];
```

How do I bind that to an ion-list and show the four items? I have tried the following, but it did not work.

```
<ion-list [(ngModel)]="Animals"/>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this code,

```
 <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of Animals">
          {{item}}
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
```

This is your string type array in component file,

```
Animals:string[] = ["Dog", "Cat", "Human", "Crab"];
```